# Restlet OAuth Extension is deprecated? Will be removed or replaced?

Tags: oauth, restlet

Restlet [changelog](https://restlet.talend.com/documentation/2.4/changelog) says that some extension will be removed with the next minor release. I could not find any information if the extension will be removed completely or reimplemented.

If the extension is no longer supported I have to search for another solution.

May somebody have more information about the current situation.

Edit:
Posted to: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1375

Comment: It seems restlet developers are no longer following through Stackoverflow questions you may just want to ask it here: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues

Comment: Try https://gitter.im/restlet-framework/community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now an official statement that the OAuth module will not be replaced but permanently deleted.

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1375#issuecomment-807236231